# ASP MVC form to call specific action and not redirect but update original page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I am using ASP.net MVC 3 for a project, and at a point now where I understand more of it, but also trying to learn differences between it and the WebForms world I have used for so long. Previously in WebForms you would just put the fields out there, add a button, and create an event, and then handle whatever you need to with with the postback.

For example, I have a simple view that shows details about an error. I want to push some of the information about this error to our issue tracker's API. Lets say just the subject and content of the error. I would in HTML do something like:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Send")" method="post">
    <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" value="@Model.subject" />
    <br />
    <input id="content" name="content" type="text" value="@Model.content" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I found that naming my input ID's to match parameter names in my controller would then let me pass these parameters. This is similar to what you see in this older post by [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx).

First of all, I want to call the 'Send' action in my Errors controller, and not my Details one. This actually does call my 'Send' action, **but then redirects to localhost/Errors/Send, which I don't want it to.**

I want to be able to submit this form, which calls and action and does the work with the remote API, and then update a message on the current page stating that the error has been transferred.

Once the issue had been submitted to the bug tracker, how do I then, for example, show a DIV on the original page passing content back to it (for example, a link to the issue in the issue tracker)?

**Update:** Here is what I am doing in my controller:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/redmine/issues.json");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write("'issue': { " +
                      "'project_id': 'project', " +
                      "'subject': 'Test issue'" +
                      "}");
}

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
string json = "";

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Also, here is what I am doing in my view (simplified, and after help from Phillip)

```
@model webapp.Models.app_errors

<script type="text/javascript">
 function SendErrors() {    

           alert(@Model); // here I get a 'webapp undefined error'
           alert(Model); // Model is undefined. If I reference @Model.App_name or another value anywhere, works fine in rest of view

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', //(probably)
            url: '../SendToRedmine',
            cache: false, //(probably)
            dataType: 'json', //(probably)
            data: @Model,
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert("The error has been transferred");
                //you can also update your divs here with the `result` object, which contains whatever your method returns
            }
            });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick='SendErrors()'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your first question, try this overload of Url.Action:

```
Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")
```

And your second question: You'll want to do it via AJAX.

Basically, for the first time the page is loaded, return whatever you want to display to the screen. Then, have an ajax function of this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendErrorsOrWhatever()
    {
        dummy = 'error: myError, someOtherProperty = property';  //this of course assumes that 'myError' and 'property' exist
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', //i changed this because it actually probably better suits the nature of your request
        url: '../Details/Send',
        cache: false, //(probably)
        dataType: 'json', //(probably)
        data: dummy,  //json object with any data you might want to use
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert("The error has been transferred");
            //you can also update your divs here with the `result` object, which contains whatever your method returns
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

A few things to note:
1) The url is automatically appended to include the data from `data`.
2) Your action method now needs to accept a parameter. There are many ways to go about this. I have added an example of what your action method might look like in the code below.

and then your button's `onclick` event will call that function, like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick='SendErrorsOrWhatever()'/>
```

What happens here is that when your button is clicked, Ajax will asynchronously (by default) hit your action method, and your action method will do whatever it needs to do with the errors, and then when it is finished, the `success` callback will be hit.

EDIT: now, your action might look something like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HTTP.Get)]
public static Error GetErrors(Error error)
{
    //do all your processing stuff
}
```

Now, this assumes that the JSon object `dummy` has the same fields as the `Error` class. If so, MVC will do automatic data binding on it. You can also use a more generic `FormCollection` for the parameter as well. Really, you can use whatever you want, but you'll want to wrap whatever you want in a JSon object.

Edit-- for your last question, this should work:

Add the following extension method to your app:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string ToJson(this Object obj)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
    }
}
```

Or if you want, you can just add a ToJson() method to your model class, and then:

```
var model = @Model.ToJson();
```

in the js right before the ajax call. Then use the `model` variable for your `data` parameter.

Comment: In this case, is my Send action actually doing the POST? As in, making my web request, handling auth, etc? Therefore, where does 'dummy' get populated?

Comment: This worked with a few minor modifications (commas really), but the only question is how do I 'load' dummy. As in, previously I was using a form and action.

Comment: Actually, `data` is the object to be *sent* to the server. So `dummy` is what you'd be sending *to* the server. What you're probably trying to "load" is `result`, in this example. `result` is returned from whatever action the ajax calls (the url) -- keep in mind in MVC that a url of the form www.x.com/Controller/Action will redirect to the "Action" action within the controller named Controller. So lets say that action returns a bool for whether or not to display the error message (you'll probably want something more complex, like a JSon object, but this is for simplicity), --

Comment: You'd then do something of the form: if(result){ //show the message }

Comment: That makes sense. I guess what I am asking is how do I put data into 'dummy', and what would happen in my controller? Currently this code calls my controller (that was actually doing the post correctly) using a HTTPWebRequest. I see how I can pass back result, just confused on how to pass from the View back to the Controller what I want to post to the service.

Comment: Oh, I see. You'll put together the `data` object in your javascript/jquery. Hang on, I'll edit this answer to show a little bit about it.

Comment: Awesome. I was about to say what I guess how does one pass parameters back to the Send action in the Details controller. And does 'Send' still actually call the remote web service and do its thing? Will update my question with what I am doing in my controller.

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to encapsulate your call to the server in the Send Action. That way, ajax will call the action asynchronously, and the action will call the web service and do whatever data manipulation you need to do. You may want to do it sync, I'm not sure. Just be careful *when* you try and work with your result when you're doing it async, because it may not exist yet.

Comment: To make that last comment a little more clear, i basically meant that:

LongRunningAsyncCallOfAnyKind();
AnotherFunctionUsingResultOfAsyncCall();

will almost certainly fail, because the result of the first call won't be ready by the time the other function is called.

Comment: One more question on your edit - with myError - can I pass the actual Model (and its values) back just like that? As in, I don't see how you define myError.

Comment: I didn't -- I was just using it as an example of what it'd look like. I was assuming myError was already defined somewhere. But yeah, if you want to pass the same model back to the controller, you can just use the `Model` object. so itd be: `data: Model,`.

Comment: And then in your controller, your action would accept an object of the same type as the model. So if your model is an ErrorModel, your parameter for the action would be an ErrorModel as well

Comment: I did that, but I get a 'Model is undefined'. If I pass back @Model, I get an 'empty' model.

Comment: What about when you try to access the model from within the view? Like, in the middle of your javascript function, if you were to add an alert(@Model)

Comment: I get something that looks like this alert(namespace.Models.app_errors ) in my HTML. If I access it elsewhere, like in the view already displaying content, it works fine (although, im doing @Model.app_name)

Comment: you don't get an actual alert pop up box when you run it? You should be getting a pop-up box with either "null", or the location of the Model in memory

Comment: I get nothing. If I run it through Chrome's JS debugger, it basically says my namespace is undefined.

Comment: can you post your relevant code? you can message it to me if you want to, or edit the original question, or whatever

Comment: Updated question. Although, I am leaning towards your current answer edit, and passing back a JSON object to the controller (since I may let the user edit something before they send). This actually works for me right now. I am very curious though how to get the enter actual model to post back to the controller though.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, an "action" is essentially a "page".  (not exactly, but with routing, this ends up being mostly true)

That is, your actions are grouped into categories and navigated to using routing within the MVC framework.

I think what you want to do here is make an AJAX call that sends your error message off to a web service.

Short of that, you can use jQuery to insert a hidden `div` that contains an `IFrame` with another action's page on it.  I wouldn't recommend it, though.

Comment: Im familiar with all of this, and actually like the actions in MVC. And I don't think thats the best way to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possiblities.

1. In your Errors/Send action redirect the user back to the localhost/Errors/Details page. This can be done with a the `Redirect()` method on the controller. The problem with this approach is it's a blocking call. And the user will have to wait until the remote api has been called and responded.
2. Use the AJAX approach as mentioned in the comments. The downside is it's a bit more complex and you may have to poll the service to retrieve the status, unless it's a fire and forget call, then it's money.

Using AJAX is the more elegant solution.

Comment: I would do it the AJAX way, and its mostly a quick call or fail. And would this be similar to what is in Philip's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using AJAX would be one of solving this. But you might want to rethink the behevior of the page. If this is your submit issue page, would you want to stay on this page after you submit an issue. What if I keep submitting issues, would you want to see the link only for the latest one? You might have to poll the server for getting a link for a submitted issue, which makes it even harder.

Without knowing the requirements, it's not easy to come up with any solution, but generally, I'd go to a different issue page once it's submitted from a submission page (something like ~/issue/id).

Also, you can use `Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.subject)` or some syntax like that, that way you won't have to match the input id manually for each property.

Comment: It's actually to send this issue to another system, using that other systems API. I basically wanted a small form to let me make an edit on anything before submitting it. Its not for actually editing the current issue, just sending that elsewhere (like a contact form almost)